# Can we use SharePoint as a backend for java Application?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, java

Can we use SharePoint as a backend for java Application? If we can what are the complication that might occur and is there any authentication required?

Please reply as soon as you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can build applications that interact with SharePoint. Though you would need to ensure that you remain within the [SharePoint limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits) and ensure that you do not exceed the limits that would incur [throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online). You can use either the Microsoft Graph or the SharePoint APIs to interact with SharePoint:

[Working with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)

Comment: Thank you So much @Callum Crowley I appreciate your help. that is really helpful.

Comment: Glad to help, remember to upvote and mark the question as accepted to help inform the community.